# How should mass be distributed in a soundproof 2 panel "mass air mass" assembly? Reducing the coincidence effect?

Tags: noise, noise-reduction

When both panels are have the same mass/area (ρₛ) and stiffness, there's the coincidence effect. The barrier becomes sound transparent at the resonance frequency of 1 panel.

Other things to consider that might have  a minor effect:

- Stiffness distribution
- the distribution of absorptive material